# Bottom bar in service console

Tags: service-cloud-console, custom, custom-console-components, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I have added a Bottom bar (visual force Page) to the contact layout in service console. I need to minimize this bottom bar conditionally in the VF page.

Comment: can you put a screenshot along with the question so that members can understand what you are looking for

Comment: I am not logged into system right now. Will update this later.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the service console integration toolkit in to your VF page, and then show/hide the window as you desire.

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/39.0/integration.js" />
<script>
// Call setVisibility on whatever elements you want.
function setVisibility(visible) {
    sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentVisible(visible);
}
</script>
```